# Accuracy in Riemann-Stieltjes integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

I have a general question regarding Riemann-Stieltjes integrals. By definition, the Riemann-Stieltjes integral I exists for a given function if for any partition of the domain of interest, I lies between the lower and upper bounds given by the partition. In the case of the Riemann Integral, using more subdivisions of the interval leads greater precision of the approximation ie. the lower and upper bounds are closer in value to real real value of the integral.

My question is:

> Under what conditions do we have greater accuracy in the Riemann-Stieltjes case, since having more subdivisions don't necessarily mean more precision?

In the case of an integrator which is a step function, having points in partition closer to the jump points of the integrator does seem to give greater precision

However, I fail to explain the intuition behind this observation

\begin{equation}
  \int_{-1}^{1} (1+x) \; d\alpha(x) \mathrm{~~~with~~~} \alpha(x) \begin{cases}
    2 & x > 0     \\
    1 & x \leq 0
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

In this example, using the partition $P = \{ -1, -0.1, 0.1, 1 \}$ of the domain $[-1,1]$ yields a lower estimate of 0.9 and upper estimate of 1.1 and also note the jump point of the integrator is at $x = 0$.

Knowing that the real value of the integral is 1 the partition $P' = \{ -1, -10^{-n}, 10^{-n}, 1 \}$ where the points to the left and to right of the jump point are closer to it, we get a precision up to $n$ decimal places ie $|L(P') - I| < 10^{-n}$ and $|U(P') - I| < 10^{-n}$.

Comment: First what is known about the integrator $\alpha$?  Is it monotonic, of bounded variation or more general.  You say the RS integral $I$ exists if "$I$ lies between the lower and upper bounds given by the partition."  What does that mean?  I would say in general that $I$ is the integral if for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a partition $P_\epsilon$ such that $|S(P,f,\alpha) - I| < \epsilon$ for any partition that refines $P_\epsilon$ where $S$ is a Riemann-Stieltjes sum.  If $\alpha$ is monotone then this can be restated in terms of Darboux-Stieltjes sums.

Comment: Also using more subdivisions does not necessarily lead to greater precision for the Riemann integral.  It depends where the subdivisions are placed.  What is true is if $P'$ is a refinement of $P$ -- meaning every point in $P$ is also in $P'$ -- then $L(P,f) \leqslant L(P',f) \leqslant I \leqslant U(P',f) \leqslant U(P,f)$.  That is , under refinement of the partition,  the upper and lower Darboux sums get closer to the integral.